# Small device to decrease air pressure around it

Tags: pressure

I want to perform a prank by creating a reduced pressure inside somebodies fridge making it impossible for them to open alone.
How could someone build something like this? I have already considered an electric pump filling a canister but are their any alternatives?

This should be preferably cheap and easy to build, but able to be disguised as an innocent gift.

Comment: This really isn't a physics question but an engineering one, which makes it off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Impractical.

You can decrease the air pressure in your own fridge just by opening the door for a few seconds, and then closing it again.  Cold air spills out while the door is open, and is replaced by warm air from the room.  Then, when you close the door, the warm air gives up its heat to the walls and contents of the fridge, and the pressure goes down.

If you try to open the door just a moment after closing it, you will find it rather difficult, but if you wait a minute longer, everything will be back to normal.  Why?  Because air leaked in.

To maintain a lower pressure inside the fridge for longer than just a few moments, you'll need to overcome the leaks by *continuously* pumping air.  But there's no way you can continuously pump air into a hidden canister.  The only way to reduce the pressure for an extended time would be to pump the air *out*.